# jquery Create array with sum of days and OT followed by project_no

Tags: jquery, arrays

I want to generate JSON array as bellow.

fully detailed array;

```
MyArray = [{ prj : "P1", days : "8", ot : "2" }, { prj : "P2", days : "8", ot : "2" }, { prj : "P2", days : "8", ot : "2" }, { prj : "P1", days : "8", ot : "2" }{prj : "P3", days : "8", ot : "2" }, { prj : "P2", days : "8", ot : "2" }, { prj : "P3", days : "8", ot : "2" }];
```

but I want to compact it as below;

```
MyArray = [{ prj : "P1", days : "16", ot : "4" }, { prj : "P2", days : "24", ot : "6" }, { prj : "P3", days : "16", ot : "4" }];
```

It should get sum of days and OT if project_number exist;

[See the example](http://jsfiddle.net/supun151515/w8ej8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, This will suit your need.

```
var MyArray = [];

//This will be used to construct your JSON object
function ConstructJson(prj, days, ot) {

    var xObj = {};
    xObj.prj = prj;
    xObj.days = days;
    xObj.ot = ot;

    MyArray[MyArray.length] = xObj;

}

 //This will minimise your json object.
function MinimiseJson() {

    var xTempArray = [];
    var xTempObj = {};
    var xPrj = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < MyArray.length; i++) {

        if (xPrj == '' && MyArray[i]) {

            xPrj = MyArray[i].prj;

            xTempObj.prj = xPrj;
            xTempObj.days = MyArray[i].days;
            xTempObj.ot = MyArray[i].ot;

            for (var j = i + 1; j < MyArray.length; j++) {

                if (MyArray[j] && MyArray[j].prj == xPrj) {

                    xTempObj.days += MyArray[j].days;
                    xTempObj.ot += MyArray[j].ot;

                    MyArray[j] = null;
                }

            }

            xPrj = '';
            xTempArray[xTempArray.length] = xTempObj;
            xTempObj = {};
        }
    }

    return xTempArray;

}
```

### [LIVE - DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rD38N/)

Comment: I have inserted more details. Please kindly look at it. I really apologize, if I make any mistake.

Comment: yeah.. correct dear... perfect try.. thank you soo much as well

Answer (score 1):

One pretty easy solution is just to loop through all the days and keep track of the sum of the values as you go through. I forked your jsfiddle as follows: http://jsfiddle.net/BM9VE/, here's the JS:

```
$(function () {
    var proj, score, MyArray = [], tally = {};
    for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        proj = $('#p' + i).val();
        score = tally[proj] || {prj: proj, days: 0, ot: 0}; // default val if we haven't seen this day yet
        score.days += parseInt($('#d' + i).val());
        score.ot += parseInt($('#ot' + i).val());
        tally[proj] = score;
    }
    for (var day in tally) {
        // your example has days and ot as strings, this code keeps them as numbers; feel free to convert them back into strings if you need to, here
        MyArray.push(tally[day]);
    }
    $('body').append('<p>MyArray: ' + JSON.stringify(MyArray) + '</p>');
});
```